# iOs 10 - SWIFT 3. Present modally and active controller when i tried to change my view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i have a problem about while change my view controllers. Here some steps what i do:

-> in my main view, i have a button to go second view. when I click the button it's okey can see second view.

-> in second view , same as first one I have a button to go back first view. when I click again can see the first view.

-> here is the problem when I came the first view second time , and click the button it's give me the following error message like:

> 'Application tried to present modally an active controller'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem could be connected with action you call on button press, you must ensure that you are always trying to present the SECOND viewcontroller from the FIRST one(not the FIRST again) and also ensure that when you come back from the SECOND one, you dismiss it(or pop it if you are using navigationController) but not simply present FIRST viewcontroller like you did before with the SECOND one.